# Easy way to copy sections to a new install

Tags: structure, sections, channels, setup

Is there an way way to copy sections I have in an existing site to a new website I am doing with a fresh install?
E.g. To Copy the News Channel Section and all the field types
Also copy the structure section and all it's entry types etc?

I suppose I could copy the full database to the new install but then all the entries would need to be deleted, e.g. all the news articles etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "easy". :)

Probably the easiest way would be to do what you describe and import the full database.  From there, you can write SQL to find all of the entries that you *don't* want to keep around from the `craft_entries` table.  If you get the IDs for those, you can remove the equivalent rows from the `craft_elements`, and Craft's cascading deletes will take care of deleting the appropriate data in the other tables.

It is on our long-term list to provide a way to import and export content between Craft installations for situations like what you're describing.